# Can I draw a line across a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, line

So I'm trying to build a chart of sorts, and I'm trying to draw multiple lines on top of a div, without displacing it. I want something sort of like this:

[image]

My current script is basically this: http://jsfiddle.net/geekongirl/sguhyuv6/1/

```
<!--html--><div id="flowsheet">
    <div class="flowsheet-title">
         <h2>This is the title</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="flowsheet-content">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 1, Box 1
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 1, Box 2
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 2, Box 1
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 2, Box 2
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 3, Box 1
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 3, Box 2
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 4, Box 1
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flowsheet-cell">Row 4, Box 2
                <div class="flowsheet-description">Here is the description box</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#flowsheet {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px;
}
.flowsheet-title {
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
}
/*individual cells*/
 .flowsheet-content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.flowsheet-cell {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:10px;
    margin: 10px 10px 15px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.flowsheet-cell:hover {
    background-color: #b5b5b5;
}
/*mousover descriptions*/
 .flowsheet-cell .flowsheet-description {
    display: none;
}
.flowsheet-cell:hover .flowsheet-description {
    background:#ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    width: 185px;
    padding:5px
}
```

I can draw a single line, or I can make a path that displaces the box. I also tried using an hr tag, but it hid itself behind the first div. Is there any way I can set up multiple lines using Java script?
Thanks!

Comment: You can, using absolute positioned `div`s.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. There's no native way to implement lines that connect divs. I'd suggest absolute `div`s, in which case you'd need to make the rest of the design somewhat absolute so everything can be positioned properly. Or, you can put the whole thing over a giant canvas and draw lines with that.

Comment: Definitely `<canvas>` IMO but a nightmare of multiple styling elements otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index` and `position`

http://jsfiddle.net/sguhyuv6/3/

You could clean that code up a lot by making better use of [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)